# git clone a project with inlined ssh credentials?

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I had configured a ssh public key in the project, and is there a way to clone the project with inline specified ssh private key?

say I had a variable $private_key,

```
echo $private_key
******
```

Now I hope I can clone a project with that $private_key in one line of shell command similar to:

```
git clone git@xxxx/yyyy.git -private_key=$private_key
```

Anyone can share some thought on this?

Background:

I configured a Jenkins Credential:
type: sshUserPrivateKey,
id: webapp

Now I want to use it in the Jenkinsfile pipeline:

```
steps {
  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'webapp', keyFileVariable: 'private_key')]) {
     sh "git clone git@xxxx/yyyy.git -private_key=${private_key}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don’t even need to specify the private key file to clone a repo using ssh url. Follow steps listed below for the SCM you use:

Github - https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Bitbucket - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

We use Bitbucket and the above instructions work like a charm